# Check if string is sorted in alphabetic order in C

Tags: c, string

I wanted to write a recursive function that gets a string pointer and returns `int`; it should return 1 if the string is in alphabetic order like "abbcdj", and otherwise it should return 0.

```
int CheckS(char *string)
{
    if (string == NULL) 
        return 1;

    if (strncmp(string, string + 1, 1) >= 0)
        CheckS(string + 1);
    else
        return 0;   
}
```

but it does not work like it's supposed to. My idea was to take a letter and the next and check if the next is coming previous in alphabetic order or not; also I check this

```
    if (string-(string+1)>=0)
        CheckS(string + 1);
```

but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should be complaining that your function does not always return a value.  It doesn't protect itself from empty strings (though it does handle null pointers, which is often good), and it mishandles the comparison of the last non-null byte with the trailing null byte in the string. Also, I think your comparison is using the wrong sign.  Using your technology, you could write:

```
int CheckS(char *string)
{
    if (string == NULL || *string == '\0' || *(string + 1) == '\0') 
        return 1;
    if (strncmp(string, string + 1, 1) <= 0)
        return CheckS(string + 1);
    else
        return 0;   
}
```

The `strncmp()` function will return a negative value if `*string` precedes `*(string + 1)`; zero if the characters are equal, and a positive value if `*string` is greater than `*(string + 1)`.  However, it would be more direct to write:

```
int CheckS(char *string)
{
    if (string == NULL || string[0] == '\0' || string[1] == '\0')
        return 1;
    if (string[0] <= string[1])
        return CheckS(string + 1);
    else
        return 0;   
}
```

Note that this does not reject or ignore non-alphabetic characters, nor does it case-convert them before comparison.  This can be regarded as GIGO — Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Also note that I'm taking the 'recursive function' as a requirement, even though the sensible code is iterative, not recursive.  The function is using a form of tail recursion, which is trivially convertible to iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you didn't try to use `strncmp` but instead just compared the next two characters. You can use `operator[]` to access the individual characters, like so:

```
string[0] >= string[1]
```

Comment: `operator []` in C?  Sorta, but it suggests you're thinking in C++.  In C, you might write 'You can use the `[]` operator', where the word 'operator' is absolutely not in `code` font.